# Drift velocity of electrons with changing area

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, velocity

What would happen with the [drift velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity) of a cylindrical resistor's diameter increases, with a given voltage between its terminals? According to the expression:

\begin{align}
R&=\rho\frac{L}{A}\\
I&=neAv_d\\
\Delta V &= IR\\
v_d&=\frac{\Delta V}{\rho L n e}\\
\end{align}

The resistivity does not change, neither does the length of the resistor nor the term $ne$ but the resistance does change as well as the current, so the area is eliminated from the expression. I wonder if the drift velocity would be the same after increasing the diameter or if my derivation is wrong.

Comment: Possibly more interesting question (but not one you asked) - what happens to the drift velocity in a conductor of non-uniform cross section? I think there the answer is that it will increase in the narrower section - resistance is higher so field strength is higher, hence greater drift. Alternatively if you think of the electrons as a "gas", continuity says that if it has to travel through a constriction it must be flowing faster.

Comment: I believe it depends, if you make infinitesimals changes in the leght, the cross section would be the same for each division and if for a given voltage the drift velocity is the same, then the changing cross sectional area wouldnt matter, but for a given current it would

Comment: I was thinking more of non uniform changes - the wire changing into an hour glass shape. Now there is a section with higher resistance per unit length. In that region the drift velocity would be higher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drift velocity is the average velocity due to an applied electric field. In a conductor, electrons scatter around at the [Fermi velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_energy) but have a net zero average (i.e., equal scattering in all directions). When the electric field is applied, the electrons are given a small velocity in one direction. Thus, we can say,
$$
v_\textrm{drift}=\eta E
$$
where $\eta$ is some constant. Since the electric field comes from a gradient in a potential, which changes as a function of the *length* of the bar, $L$. This approximates to
$$
v_\textrm{drift}\simeq\eta\frac{V}{L}
$$
which is similar to what you have. Since there is no factor of $A$ in the latter equation (not in my $\eta$ here), then increasing the area (by increasing the diameter) should not change the drift velocity.